# Why Android Service and Activity executing asynchronously in the main Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-service

This might be a very basic question and often I have been asked this question in interviews and all, but I'm unable to find a proper clear answer for this, That's why asking here

I have a simple service as follows

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "MyService";

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + i + " in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }           
    }
```

The service prints 1 to 10 with a slight delay.

And I have this code in activty onCreate

```
          @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));   // starting the service    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);  // waiting for 5 seconds after service started
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate completed");
            }
```

Since I have  used the normal Service, it is executing in the main thread where your activity is running.

So, ideally it should first execute the service code and finally it will print the  `"onCreate completed"` which is the last line in `onCreate` , since we have only one thread to do all these

But while running what I can see is,

```
  // here is a delay of 5 seconds and after that the following prints
  onCreate: completed
  onStartCommand: 0 in main
  onStartCommand: 1 in main
  onStartCommand: 2 in main
  onStartCommand: 3 in main
  onStartCommand: 4 in main
  onStartCommand: 5 in main
  onStartCommand: 6 in main
  onStartCommand: 7 in main
  onStartCommand: 8 in main
  onStartCommand: 9 in main
```

As you can see, even if I'm starting service first, and putting a delay afterwards, `onCreate finishes` the execution first.

Then only service is staring execution in the main thread. Why is that?

My understanding is , the Android OS will create and prepare the service component for execution in a different Thread, and when it is ready, we will get the `onCreate` callback in service in the main thread. Till then, OS prepares in Asynchronously.

Is that correct?

If anyone could give a detailed explanation of what is happening behind the scenes, it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Services are attached to main-thread unless they are asked to be run in a different process in manifest - which are technically still the main-thread but of a different process. It is IntentService that runs on a different thread. Don't confuse Service with IntentService. Read more on this on android's official docs.

Comment: AFAIK there is no second thread - when you call `startService` message to start it is put in main threads [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper) queue, and executed only after activitys `onCreate` concludes.

Comment: @waqaslam It's not an `IntentService` notmal Service only

Comment: You'll find that `Service.onCreate()`, then `Service.onStartCommand()` execute (on the main thread) shortly after you return from `Activity.onCreate()`. So far as I know, this process only involves one thread; it's just the message loop that makes things appear asynchronous. And it also explains why the `Service` lifecycle doesn't advance until after you return from `Activity.onCreate()`; the message loop needs you to return control to it, so it can continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: in `onCreate()`, calling `startService()` is just a request to start the `Service`. Since a `Service` will run on the main thread, all its methods can only be executed once `onCreate()` has finished.

With `Thread.sleep(5000);` the main thread is blocked by  `onCreate()` for five seconds.  After you write to Logcat as last step in this method, the main thread is free to run the next scheduled method.

Useful link: [Understanding Android Core: Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)

Comment: So, in this case, in which life-cycle of the activity the service will actually be running? After `onResume`?

Comment: @user3339689 - I never saw any guaranteed time at which a Service will be up and running. But you can either use a bound Service and have it send a message to the Activity via a Handler or you send a broadcast using [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) from the Service once it considers itself to be running. Interested parties (e.g. your Activity) would have to register a BroadcastReceiver with a matching IntentFilter